# Platformio Error does not name a type

Tags: platformio

I have  very simply code:

main.cpp

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "config.h"

Config c;

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

config.h

```
#ifndef Config_h
#define Config_h

class Config{
  public:
    Config(){};
  };

#endif
```

config.cpp

```
#include "config.h"
```

When I try to build project, I got the below error:

> src\main.cpp:4:1: error: 'Config' does not name a type

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution config.h => myconfig.h

Comment: this is solution but what caused the problem